# ValidationError: Invoice validation failed: date: Cast to Date failed in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was trying to make an application which created invoices and it was working fine before I encountered this error:

```
(node:21336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Invoice validation failed: date: Cast to Date failed for value "29-10-2020" at path "date"
at new ValidationError (C:\Users\mynam\Desktop\covid-19\IWP_Accounting-Project_18BCI0168\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:31:11)
at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\mynam\Desktop\covid-19\IWP_Accounting-Project_18BCI0168\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2394:32)
at model.$set (C:\Users\mynam\Desktop\covid-19\IWP_Accounting-Project_18BCI0168\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1175:12)
at model._handleIndex (C:\Users\mynam\Desktop\covid-19\IWP_Accounting-Project_18BCI0168\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:930:14)
at model.$set (C:\Users\mynam\Desktop\covid-19\IWP_Accounting-Project_18BCI0168\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:874:22)
at model.Document (C:\Users\mynam\Desktop\covid-19\IWP_Accounting-Project_18BCI0168\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:136:12)
at model.Model (C:\Users\mynam\Desktop\covid-19\IWP_Accounting-Project_18BCI0168\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:93:12)
at new model (C:\Users\mynam\Desktop\covid-19\IWP_Accounting-Project_18BCI0168\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4419:15)
at model (C:\Users\mynam\Desktop\covid-19\IWP_Accounting-Project_18BCI0168\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4414:16)
at C:\Users\mynam\Desktop\covid-19\IWP_Accounting-Project_18BCI0168\routes\invoice.js:58:13
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:21336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

As far as I could understand, it was failing to catch some async functions. The date format I accept through the code is of type "dd-mm-yyyy" which should be acceptable for mongoDB. How can I proceed to rectify this error:

The form submission of the website:

[image]

I will readily update the posts with any other file codes required to rectify the error. Which files should I look at to do so. Thank you

The invoice.js file lines where the error is pointing to (the `invoice=Invoice({` line):

```js
router.post('/new', async(req,res) => {
    if (req.session.companyId == null || req.session.companyId == '') {
        res.send("Please select Company")
    }
    
    // console.log(req.body)
    try {
        x = await Party.findByGstin(req.body.partyId)
        req.body.partyId = x._id
    }
    catch(e) {
        //console.log(e)
    }
    
    invoice = Invoice({
        partyId: req.body.partyId,
        date:  req.body.date,
        number: req.body.number,
        totalAmount: req.body.totalAmount,
        narration: req.body.narration,
        eWay: req.body.eWay,
        companyId: req.session.companyId
    })
    
    invoice = await invoice.save()
    var items = []
    var num = 0
    var serialNumbersObj = {}
    keys = Object.keys(req.body)
    for(const key of keys){
        x = req.body[key]
        //console.log(key, x)
        if(key.substring(0,12)=="select_item_")
        {
            items.push([key,x.substring(14,)])
        }
        if(key.substring(0,7)=="myModal")
        {
            if(key.substring(7,8)=="_")
            {
                num = Number(key.substring(7,8))*10 + Number(key.substring(8,9))
            }
            else
            {
                num = Number(key.substring(7,8))
            }
            if(serialNumbersObj[num.toString(10)]==undefined)
            {
                serialNumbersObj[num.toString(10)] = []
            }
            serialNumbersObj[num.toString(10)].push(x)
        }
    }
    //console.log("\n\n")
    //console.log(serialNumbersObj)
    //console.log(items)
    var itemDetails = []
    //console.log("\n\n")
    for(const item in items)
    {
        //console.log(items[item])
        const item1 = items[item][0].substring(12,)
        const quantity = req.body['quantity_' + item1]
        const rate_per = req.body['rate_per_' + item1]
        itemDetails.push([item1, items[item][1], quantity, rate_per, serialNumbersObj[item1]])
    }
    //console.log("\n\n")
    //console.log(itemDetails)
    for(const itemDetail in itemDetails)
    {
        //console.log(itemDetails[itemDetail])
        try{
            item_id  = await Item.getByName(itemDetails[itemDetail][1])
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            console.log(e)
        }
        //console.log(invoice._id, item_id, Number(itemDetails[itemDetail][3]), Number(itemDetails[itemDetail][2]))
        
        invoice_item = InvoiceItem({
            invoiceId : invoice._id, 
            itemId: item_id._id, 
            ratePer : Number(itemDetails[itemDetail][3]), 
            quantity : Number(itemDetails[itemDetail][2])
        })
        
        invoice_item = await invoice_item.save()
        console.log(invoice_item)
        for(const serial of itemDetails[itemDetail][4])
        {
            serialNo = SerialNumber({
                invoiceItemId : invoice_item._id,
                serialNumber : serial
            })
            serialNo.save()
        }
    }
    //x.forEach(function(key, ))
    
    return res.redirect('/invoice/list')
})
```

The invoice model

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const InvoiceItem = require('./invoiceItem')
const InvoiceItemSerialNumber = require('./serialNumber')


const InvoiceSchema = new Schema({
    partyId: {type: String, trim: true ,default: '', required:true},
    date: {type: Date, trim: true, default: ''},
    number: {type: String, trim: true, default: ''},
    totalAmount: {type: Number, trim:true ,default: ''},
    narration: {type: String, trim:true ,default: ''},
    eWay: {type: String, trim:true ,default: ''},
    companyId: {type: String, trim: true ,default: '', required: true}    
})


InvoiceSchema.statics.findById = async (_id) => {
    console.log(_id)
    const invoice = await Invoice.findOne({
        _id
    })
    
    if (!invoice) {
        throw new Error('Unable to find invoice')
    }
    
    // console.log(user)
    return invoice
}


InvoiceSchema.statics.deleteinvoice = async (_id) => {
    try{
        //console.log("inside function",companyid,typeof data)
        const res = await Invoice.findByIdAndDelete(_id)
        
        if(!res){
            throw newError('No invoice with given id')
        }
        
        return true
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log(e)
    }
}


InvoiceSchema.statics.findByCompanyId = async (companyId)=> {
    
    const invoices = await Invoice.find({companyId})
    
    if(!invoices)
    {
        throw new Error('No invoice found')
    }
    
    return invoices
}

InvoiceSchema.statics.updateinvoice = async (partyid, data) => {
    try{
        //console.log("inside function",partyid,typeof data)
        const res = await Invoice.updateOne({_id: partyid}, data)
        
        if(!res){
            throw newError('No invoice with given id')
        }
        
        return true
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

InvoiceSchema.statics.countTotalDoucments = async (companyId) => {
    try{
        console.log(companyId)
        const res = await Invoice.where({companyId:companyId}).countDocuments()
        
        if(!res){
            throw new Error('No invoice with given id')
        }
        
        return res
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

const Invoice = mongoose.model('Invoice', InvoiceSchema);
module.exports = Invoice;
```

Comment: Please don't paste (hardly readable) images. Use formatted text for error and code.

Comment: sorry for the hassle, edited the question

Comment: The error stack exactly tells you where to error appears: file `C:\Users\mynam\Desktop\covid-19\IWP_Accounting-Project_18BCI0168\routes\invoice.js` at line 58. NB, did you really install the application in your personal desktop folder?

Comment: yes, I updated the question with the file contents for the `invoice.js` file, the error is pointing towards the `invoice_item = InvoiceItem({` line in the given function

Comment: Don't put er entire file. Locate the error an provide relevant pieces. SO is not a "code analyzing service".

Comment: I updated it with the error statements, I'm a bit confused and can't understand what is the main cause of the error, so put in as much as I could.

Comment: first of all, you need to wrap all the async calls inside of a try/catch block, here I am specifically talking about this line `invoice = await invoice.save()`, in the catch block you will have the error object, which can be used to send the user an appropriate response.

Comment: OMG! - next step is to check file `../models/invoice/invoice` and have a look at the constructor for `Invoice`

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question with the invoice constructor file.

Comment: mongoose date type takes in the data in this form `2002-12-09`, whereas you are providing it in the form of `29-10-2020`, which is why you are getting an error.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit is right, you gotta follow the error, see where and what exactly it is saying. 90% of the times error stack trace is very descriptive and will help you locate the issue.

Comment: @RaghavGarg is it possible to change the date format while passing through the date input field or should I change the date constructor to take in string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go: `date: {type: Date, trim: true, default: ''}`. The constructor expects a `Date` object but you pass a string `"29-10-2020"`.

Have a look at [JavaScript Date Formats](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp):

> **WARNINGS !**
>
> The behavior of  "DD-MM-YYYY" is also undefined.
> Some browsers will try to guess the format. Some will return NaN.
>
> `var d = new Date("25-03-2015");`

That's exactly where you run into.

I am a bit surprised about the defaults. Why having default **string** `''` for `Number` and `Date` data types?

Comment: Should I change the constructor to pass in string? Will doing so fix the main error (even though it is not the right thing to do ), or can I change the format of date passed through the text field

Comment: may I request you for a chat session, I have some queries and errors after doing this

Comment: I am not a free JavaScript trainer. Actually I never used mongoose or node.js so far. If you face problems, please open a new question. In the internet you should find thousands of examples how to create a `Date` object.

Comment: The date object problem was fixed I think but now the invoice.js is giving some other errors so I wanted to clarify them up, I only need the guidance as to how to do them, if it wouldn't be possible I understand, thank you for your help!